# Get-Content piped with Add-Content

Tags: powershell

I encountered something weird I do not understand. My scenario:

I have in `C:\Functions` multiple .ps1 files. I would like to copy the content of the files to one file (`AllFunctions.ps1`). The file `CopyFunctions2AllFunctions.ps1` is the file that execudes my commands.

```
$path="C:\Functions\*.ps1"
$destination="C:\Functions\AllFunctions.ps1"

Clear-Content -Path C:\Functions\AllFunctions.ps1

Get-Content -Path $path -Exclude "C:\Functions\CopyFunctions2AllFunctions.ps1"  | Add-Content -Path $destination
```

The error message is in german, however, it says AllFunctions.ps1 cannot be accessed, because it is used in another process.

The code works if replace

```
$path="C:\Functions\*.ps1"
```

with a specific file name like

```
$path="C:\Functions\Read-Date.ps1"
```

`-Force` didnt help

Also, the code worked until `Add-Content -Path $destination`. When I executed `Get-Content...` the terminal didnt show me just what was inside the .ps1 files, but also the content of the terminal, with all the errors I encountered while trying...

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: grab all the `Get-Content` input into a $Var ... and only then send things to your output file. ///// the problem is that you are reading ONE item, processing it, _and then changing the file listing_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to be fixed in this code, first the new code:

```
$path="C:\Functions"
$destination="C:\Functions\AllFunctions.ps1"

Clear-Content -Path C:\Functions\AllFunctions.ps1

$functions=Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude CopyFunctions2Profile.ps1 | Get-Content

Add-Content -Path $destination -Value $functions
```

Issue #1

`$path="C:\Functions\*.ps1"` doesnt work, PS is also copying the content of the terminal, I dont know why...Therefore, we dont use wildcards in our $path.

Because of that we need to use `Get-Childitem` in the code as the following:

```
$functions=Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude CopyFunctions2Profile.ps1 | Get-Content
```

Issue #2

Working with pipes, PS processes one item and sends it through the pipe, then the second and so on. Due to that, when item 2 is sent to `Add-Content`, "AllFunctions.ps1" is still being used for item 1.

Therefore, we need to save our `Get-Content` in a variable `($functions)` and then use it in `Add-Content`.